Were larger trusted setups run?
Vitalik said here that the plan was to run multiple trusted setups, with 4096th, 8192th, 16384th, and 32768th roots of unity. Have all those setups been run, and if so, are the outputs available anywhere? (The output from the 4096th roots are here, but I haven't found the others.)

I found them... They're here.
